# Регулярное выражение до последнего вхождения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть html страница и нужно вытащить блок

```
<div>
блабла
</div>
```

Если использовать регулярное выражение

`reg = @"<div>([\s\S]*)</div>";`

то он выдаст:

```
<div>
блабла
</div>
вся остальная HTML страница
</div>
```

То есть он выдает не до первого вхождения `</div>`, а до последнего.
Как правильно составить рег. выражение?

P.S. я знаю, что для парсинга html страниц рег. выражения не подходят, просто уже не раз сталкивался с этой проблемой, не только при обработке html, но всегда умудрялся ее обойти. А сейчас решил разобраться.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. Нужно меньше жадничать)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как вы сами сказали, не следует использовать регулярные выражения для разбора HTML.
2. Попробуйте нежадный квантификатор: `<div>([\s\S]*?)</div>`.

Comment: Пожалуйста!